# Exact same jquery code works in one html document and not another

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use the EXACT SAME jQuery code. It works in one html document but not in the second. I'm using CSS in these documents as well. Both the CSS and the jQuery code are not in external files. I feel like the solution is probably something simple so forgive me for my lack of knowledge. I will leave the jQuery code, the CSS code, the html code that isn't functioning with the jQuery and exactly how it looks in the document(all in one). I will list them in that exact order.

JQUERY CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".showr").click(function(){
    $(".vidr").css('visibility','visible');
    $(".vids").css('visibility','hidden');
  });
  $(".shows").click(function(){
    $(".vidr").css('visibility','hidden');
    $(".vids").css('visibility','visible');
  });
    $(".left").click(function(){  
    $(".showr").animate({"left":"-=110px"},"slow");
    $(".shows").animate({"left":"-=110px"},"slow");
  });
    $(".right").click(function(){  
    $(".showr").animate({"left":"+=110px"},"slow");
    $(".shows").animate({"left":"+=110px"},"slow");
  });
});
</script>
```

CSS CODE:

```
<style type="text/css">
html,body
{
padding:0;
margin:0;
height:1200px;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
body
{
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:hidden;
}
.stretch
{
width:100%;
height:1200px;
position:relative;
z-index:-2;
}
.topmenu
{
position:relative;
top:-2400px;
left:100px;
z-index:-1;
}
.videoplayer
{
position:relative;
top:-3600px;
left:100px;
z-index:-1;
}
.videoscroller
{
position:relative;
top:-4800px;
left:100px;
z-index:-1;
}
.twitterfeed
{
position:relative;
top:-8755px;
left:100px;
z-index:-1;
}
.slider
{
position:relative;
left:263px;
bottom:3050px;
z-index:0;
overflow:hidden;
width:485px;
height:160px;
margin:0px; 
padding:5px;
background:#e5eecc;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
div.left
{
position:relative;
left:208px;
bottom:3175px;
z-index:0;
overflow:hidden;
width:42px;
height:80px;
margin:0px; 
padding:5px;
background:black;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
div.right
{
position:relative;
left:761px;
bottom:3272px;
z-index:0;
overflow:hidden;
width:42px;
height:80px;
margin:0px; 
padding:5px;
background:white;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
div.videos
{
position:absolute;
left:210px;
top:138px;
z-index:1;
width:592px;
height:383px;
margin:0px; 
padding:5px;
}
iframe
{
position:absolute;
left:20px;
top:20px;
}
img.showr
{
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
}
img.shows
{
position:absolute;
left:180px;
z-index:2;
}

</style>
```

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div><img src="Background2IBSTV.jpg" class="stretch"/>
</div>
<div style="position:relative; top:-1200px; left:100px;" class="stretch"><img src="railsIBSTV.png"/>
</div>
<div class="topmenu"><img src="Top_MenuIBSTV.png"/>
</div>
<div class="videoplayer"><img src="video_playerIBSTV.png"/>
<div class="videos">
<iframe class="vidr" style="visibility:hidden;" width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/nwYYaqs_yM4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe class="vids" style="visibility:hidden;" width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/fO4aXYETHxE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<div class="videoscroller"><img src="video_scrollerIBSTV.png"/>
<img src="left_arrowIBSTV.png" style="position:relative; left:-22px; bottom:1200px;"/>
<img src="right_arrowIBSTV.png" style="position:relative; left:22px; bottom:2400px;"/>
<div class="slider">
<img src="rampage-jackson.jpg" class="showr" width="165" height="150">
<img src="Professional.jpg" class="shows" width="165" height="150">
</div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
</div>
<div class="twitterfeed"><img src="twitter_feedIBSTV.png"/><p style="position:relative; left:455px; bottom:450px; font-size:35px; color:lightgrey;">Twitter</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

ALL IN ONE (Exactly how it looks in document)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".showr").click(function(){
    $(".vidr").css('visibility','visible');
    $(".vids").css('visibility','hidden');
  });
  $(".shows").click(function(){
    $(".vidr").css('visibility','hidden');
    $(".vids").css('visibility','visible');
  });
    $(".left").click(function(){  
    $(".showr").animate({"left":"-=110px"},"slow");
    $(".shows").animate({"left":"-=110px"},"slow");
  });
    $(".right").click(function(){  
    $(".showr").animate({"left":"+=110px"},"slow");
    $(".shows").animate({"left":"+=110px"},"slow");
  });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
html,body
{
padding:0;
margin:0;
height:1200px;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
body
{
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:hidden;
}
.stretch
{
width:100%;
height:1200px;
position:relative;
z-index:-2;
}
.topmenu
{
position:relative;
top:-2400px;
left:100px;
z-index:-1;
}
.videoplayer
{
position:relative;
top:-3600px;
left:100px;
z-index:-1;
}
.videoscroller
{
position:relative;
top:-4800px;
left:100px;
z-index:-1;
}
.twitterfeed
{
position:relative;
top:-8755px;
left:100px;
z-index:-1;
}
.slider
{
position:relative;
left:263px;
bottom:3050px;
z-index:0;
overflow:hidden;
width:485px;
height:160px;
margin:0px; 
padding:5px;
background:#e5eecc;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
div.left
{
position:relative;
left:208px;
bottom:3175px;
z-index:0;
overflow:hidden;
width:42px;
height:80px;
margin:0px; 
padding:5px;
background:black;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
div.right
{
position:relative;
left:761px;
bottom:3272px;
z-index:0;
overflow:hidden;
width:42px;
height:80px;
margin:0px; 
padding:5px;
background:white;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
div.videos
{
position:absolute;
left:210px;
top:138px;
z-index:1;
width:592px;
height:383px;
margin:0px; 
padding:5px;
}
iframe
{
position:absolute;
left:20px;
top:20px;
}
img.showr
{
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
}
img.shows
{
position:absolute;
left:180px;
z-index:2;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div><img src="Background2IBSTV.jpg" class="stretch"/>
</div>
<div style="position:relative; top:-1200px; left:100px;" class="stretch"><img src="railsIBSTV.png"/>
</div>
<div class="topmenu"><img src="Top_MenuIBSTV.png"/>
</div>
<div class="videoplayer"><img src="video_playerIBSTV.png"/>
<div class="videos">
<iframe class="vidr" style="visibility:hidden;" width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/nwYYaqs_yM4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe class="vids" style="visibility:hidden;" width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/fO4aXYETHxE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<div class="videoscroller"><img src="video_scrollerIBSTV.png"/>
<img src="left_arrowIBSTV.png" style="position:relative; left:-22px; bottom:1200px;"/>
<img src="right_arrowIBSTV.png" style="position:relative; left:22px; bottom:2400px;"/>
<div class="slider">
<img src="rampage-jackson.jpg" class="showr" width="165" height="150">
<img src="Professional.jpg" class="shows" width="165" height="150">
</div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
</div>
<div class="twitterfeed"><img src="twitter_feedIBSTV.png"/><p style="position:relative; left:455px; bottom:450px; font-size:35px; color:lightgrey;">Twitter</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you getting any error ?? use firebug console and check for errros. you can generalize the code by using toggle..

Comment: I kind of stopped reading at jQuery version 1.2.6. It's horribly outdated, that's where jQuery was 3 years ago. Please consider updating to a newer version, the latest one is 1.6.1

Comment: @kobe I didn't get any errors for the code. That's why I don't understand why it's not working. I used google's online jQuery compiler to check.

Comment: @DarthJDG Ok, I'll make sure to update the version. That shouldn't stop the code from functioning with the code I've shown right?                                                              @mu is too short : By "doesn't work" I mean the click functions I'm using don't fire and my effects linked to them don't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is with the version of jquery and/or clashes between inline styles and stylesheet styles.

I set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amelvin/f8kpy/) and if you run your HTML and jquery nothing happens on jquery 1.2.6 but the code works OK on jquery versions 1.3.2, 1.4.4, 1.5.2, 1.6.

I didn't include the css in the fiddle because you have inline styles as well as using a stylesheet - the clashes between the two break the page on js fiddle, so I guess there are conflicts causing unwanted side-effects.

I would switch to using helper methods rather than directly referencing CSS styles; so use:

```
$(".vidr").hide();
```

rather than:

```
$(".vidr").css('visibility','hidden');
```

And you might want to look at the [jquery animate function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) because I'm not sure whether your use of it is achieving what it is you want it to.

Comment: I changed the version of jquery to 1.6.1 and change the .css(visibility) functions to .hide functions. I'm still having problems with getting the jquery functions to fire at all. I suspect that it might have something to do with the css I used because of the positioning of the images I'm trying to attach click functions to. I have them as position:absolute and z-index:2; in front of everything else in the document. Could positioning be a source of the problem? Let me know if you need to see the changes I made to the code that you suggested.

Comment: @Rambo Your click functions work - I got the events to fire by entirely removing the separate CSS and just using the inline styles and a newer version of jquery.  I also added an alt attribute to the images so that there was something to click on in jsfiddle - otherwise they render invisibly as jsfiddle can't find them.

Comment: THANKS! I took away the CSS and it worked. It must've been something with the inline styles and the CSS that clashed because I got rid of the inline styles, put them in the CSS and changed up the CSS. After that it worked with the document looking how I wanted it to.